# How can I view data of specific dates in MS Access DB

Tags: ms-access, northwind

I'm using Northwind DB in MS Access I'm facing problem in viewing the data with specific dates. I have created a new form and I want to get the data in the form for my end user. So if he specifies from and till dates the corresponding data should appear in the form.

How it can be done in form ?

Ex. In table dbo_invoices I want to know the order list for specific time I.e ddmmyyyy to ddmmyyyy and display all the elements in the given time. 
How can it be done.

Thank you. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use dates as criteria you should read here :
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762

As  for your specific need in the query you should use on the date field

```
Between [dateFrom] and [dateTo]
```